# asp.net mvc3, Roles from database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authorization

I am creating a asp.net mvc project which I want to manage the roles in the database.

I have a database with a table, in the table Called Premissions I have a column (AdministratorRole) that contains roles for my mvc project, the value will hold something like `'Domain\John Smith'` (the users). I want my mvc project to check this column each time it starts up.

In my mvc project i am using the Authorize attribute in the controllers:

```
[Authorize(Roles = Roles.AdministratorRole)]
```

I was thinking of creating a Interface so I can use a `IQueryable` to query the database, and then add something in the Global.asax file in the `application_start` method so that it runs the interface first and check all roles. (How can I do this?)

This is so we can maintain the roles in the database rather than in the code of the project.

How can I do this please?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

ASP.Net uses a Provider model for Membership and Roles. If you are doing something custom, then you simply need to create a [Custom RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can implement a [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

> ASP.NET role management enables you to easily use a number of
>   different providers for your ASP.NET applications. You can use the
>   supplied profile providers that are included with the .NET Framework,
>   or you can implement your own provider.
>
> There are two primary reasons for creating a custom role provider.
>
> You need to store role information in a data source that is not
>   supported by the role providers included with the .NET Framework, such
>   as a FoxPro database, an Oracle database, or other data source.
>
> You need to manage role information using a database schema that is
>   different from the database schema used by the providers that ship
>   with the .NET Framework. A common example of this would be
>   authorization data that already exists in a SQL Server database for a
>   company or Web site.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply, do you guys have any example code that I can work from? I am a new user of asp.net mvc im afriad.

Comment: There is a [complete example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/317sza4k(v=vs.100).aspx) linked from RoleProvider link above.